# How to update Python version in root environment in conda

Tags: python, conda

Simple question: How do I update from Python 3.5 to 3.6 in my root environment in conda? That is, I don't want to create a new Python 3.6 environment; I want my root environment to change to Python 3.6

I've tried

```
conda update --all python=3.6
```

This updates packages, but not the Python version.

I've also tried

```
conda install python=3.6
```

I get an UnsatisfiableError

Comment: Probably because you have some packages that are incompatible with Python 3.6 in your current root environment. Unfortunately, the `UnsatisfiableError` message is not very helpful, and can be misleading or wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the `UnsatisfiableError` said something about Python 2.6, which is a version I've never had installed in any environment on this computer.

Comment: Any ideas how to figure out what the offending package is?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. The `UnsatisfiableError` said something about "argcomplete". I thought that was an opaque part of the error message, but it's actually a package. I removed that and then had to remove a few other packages and I was able to get it to update.

Answer (score 3):

Run this:

```
conda install anaconda=4.3
```

Read this:
https://www.scivision.co/switch-anaconda-python-36/

Comment: I get a message saying all requested packages are already installed. Apparently I already have Anaconda 4.3.1, but Python is still version 3.5.

I also tried `conda install anaconda=4.3 python=3.6` and I get an `UnsatisfiableError` again.

Comment: Eric: I had this very same problem. I moved my anaconda3 directory to anaconda3.old and re-ran the installation and that made everything become as expected.

My guess is that the anaconda installer relies on version numbers for conda but doesn't update the python version properly. I tried every proposed solution out there until I resorted to this one.